# how to create on button click start repeated notifications with specific time interval and on click stop notifications in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-notifications

creating a water remainder app and stuck on this for two days. there are 3 buttons to 15min, 30min, 60min user can click any one of this button then by clicking on Start Remainder button application will generate notification reminders ("Time to Drink Water") for every 15,30 or 60 min based on selected button. On click Stop Reminder button all reminders will end. am new to android trying my best and i hope stackoverflow community will help.

waterRemainder.java

```
public class waterRemainder extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button min15, min30, min60, rstart, rstop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_water_remainder);

        min15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.min15);
        min15.setOnClickListener(this);

        min30 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.min30);
        min30.setOnClickListener(this);

        min60 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.min60);
        min60.setOnClickListener(this);

        rstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rstart);
        rstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StartRemainder();
            }
        });

        rstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rstop);
        rstart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StopRemainder();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.min15:
                SetRemainder(15);
            case R.id.min30:
                SetRemainder(30);
            case R.id.min60:
                SetRemainder(60);
        }

    }

    public void SetRemainder(int minutes){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,5);

    }

    public void StartRemainder(){

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(waterRemainder.this,"My Notification")
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setContentText("its working")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

    }

    public void StopRemainder(){

    }
}
```

activity_water_remainder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
    tools:context=".waterRemainder">
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/min15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="15 Min"
        android:layout_above="@+id/min30"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/min30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30 Min"
        android:layout_above="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="60 Min"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rstart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="START&#10;REMINDER"
        android:layout_below="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rstop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STOP&#10;REMINDER"
        android:layout_below="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/min60"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SetRemainder function do the following:

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            //here you can show notification method 
        }
    }, delay, period);
}
```

where delay is the amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.. In your case set it to 0 and period is the amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions which in your case will be the 'minutes' variable.

And write timer.cancel(); in the stop method to cancel the timer.